# Get Scope identity for multiple inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
For table1 Inserted 3 records
```

It should get those three identities and it should insert  3 records in table3 (but it’s not happening- it inserts 3 records with same identity ie.last scope identity)

```
 create table table1(ID INT identity(1,1),Name varchar(50))
    insert into table1 values('Ram'),('Sitha'),('Laxman')
    create table table1(ID INT identity(1,1),Name varchar(50))
    create table table3(ID INT ,Name varchar(50))

    insert into table2(Name)
    select Name from table1
        declare @id int;
        set @id= (select scope_Identity())
    begin
    insert into table3(ID,Name)
    select @id,Name from table2
    end

    select * from table2
    select * from table3
```

How can get all identities to insert do I need to write a loop (or) do I need to Create a trigger.

Please give me a solution I am strugguling from past 4 hours.

Thanks in anvance

Comment: How many tables do you want, 2 or 3? Can you correct your code above.

Comment: Also, do you want a solution for 1 INSERT (OUTPUT clause will suffice) or *any* insert (you want a TRIGGER)?

Comment: I tried bellow solution but I am getting following error

The target table 'table2' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found reference constraint 'FK_table2_ID'.

I just want insert if Trigger is necessary to do this then we will go for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the OUTPUT clause to handle multi-row inserts:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table2(Name)
OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.Name INTO table3
SELECT Name FROM dbo.table1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan Guzman......
But I am getting following errror!

The target table 'table2' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found reference constraint 'FK_table2_ID'.

Comment: @Balaji Gollapalli - The error is telling you what's wrong: the target of the OUTPUT...INTO clause can't have FK relationships. Nothing wrong with the sql as written, you just need to target a different table.

Comment: @Balaji Gollapalli, for a table with foreign key constraints, you can declare a local table variable with the same structure as table3 and specify that in the `OUTPUT` clause.  Then use an INSERT...SELECT to insert into table3 from the table variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OUTPUT clause to get the identity from any number of inserts.

```
create table table1(ID INT identity(1,1),Name varchar(50))
DECLARE @T1 Table (ID int, name varchar(50))
insert into table1 
    OUTPUT inserted.ID, Inserted.Name INTO @T1
    values('Ram'),('Sitha'),('Laxman')
```

Comment: The target table 'table2' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found reference constraint 'FK_table2_ID'.

Comment: Output into a table variable, then process the data in the table variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @IdentityId INT,@Count INT=1
    DECLARE  @temp AS TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY ,Name NVARCHAR(100))

   INSERT INTO @temp(Name)
   SELECT Name FROM table1

   WHILE @Count <=(SELECT COUNT(SId) FROM @temp)
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO table2(Name)
    SELECT Name FROM @temp
        WHERE Id=@Count

        SET @IdentityId  = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        INSERT INTO tabel3(@IdentityId,Name)
        SELECT 3, @IdentityId,1,GETDATE() 
        SET @Count=@Count+1
   END
```